How to Manage Transactions with Multiple DbContexts in a .NET Application while Using a Custom NuGet Package?
I'm working on a .NET application where I need to manage transactions across multiple DbContext instances. My application uses a custom NuGet package that interacts with the database using Entity Framework Core. The NuGet package has its own DbContext and creates its own transaction scope. However, I need this to participate in a broader transaction scope initiated in the calling application to ensure all operations are atomic. Both DBContext using the same MSSQL Database.
Problem Details:
Context: My application creates a transaction scope using TransactionScope and performs operations across multiple DbContext instances.
NuGet Package Behavior: The NuGet package creates a new transaction scope using its own DbContext, which can lead to nested or distributed transactions, causing unexpected behavior.
My application:
public async Task ProcessDataAsync(ProcessDataDto processDataDto, Guid? entityId = null) {
    using var transactionScope = transactionScopeFactory.CreateTransactionScope();

    var newEntityId = await dataProvider.SaveEntityAsync(...);

    await customNuGetPackage.FinalizeEntityAsync(newEntityId); // This triggers the NuGet package code

    transactionScope.Complete();
 }

NuGet:
 public async Task ExecAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncAction, int timeoutInSec =      ElproEventDbContext.DefaultTimeoutInSec) where T : DbContext
     {
    using var context = Create(timeoutInSec);
    var strategy = context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
    try
    {
        await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await asyncAction.Invoke(context as T));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogCritical(ex, "Exception while executing SQL statement");
        throw;
    }
    }

    protected virtual DbContext Create(int timeoutInSec)
    {
    var context = new ElproEventDbContext(logger, connectionStringProvider);
    context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(timeoutInSec);

    return context;
    }

What I tried:
I tried modifying the ExecAsync method in my custom NuGet package to manage transactions more effectively. Specifically, I checked if there was an existing transaction using context.Database.CurrentTransaction. If a transaction was already active, I expected the method to reuse it. If no transaction was active, I created a new one with  context.Database.BeginTransaction().
 public async Task ExecAsync<T>(Func<T, Task> asyncAction, int timeoutInSec = 300) where T :     DbContext
    {
    var context = Create(timeoutInSec);
    var strategy = context.Database.CreateExecutionStrategy();
    try
    {
        await strategy.ExecuteAsync(async () =>
        {
            using (var transaction = 
     context.Database.CurrentTransaction ?? context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                await asyncAction.Invoke(context as T);

                if (context.Database.CurrentTransaction != null)
                {
                    await context.Database.CurrentTransaction.CommitAsync();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogCritical(ex, "Exception while executing SQL statement");
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        context?.Dispose();
    }
    }


Are all of the connection strings the same?  If so the different DBContext instances can share a single SQL Server connection behind the scenes.
